# Setting the default selection tab for CSS/JS tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the example here, I have created tabs that respond as I want. But, I want to set the default selection tab when the page is loaded.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

I've tried this answer, and while it does adjust the URL, it doesn't seem to actually load the default tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21363375/680268

Answer (score 1):

Run the `function openCity(evt, cityName)` when your page loaded and put into the parameter the city you want to start with.
Example:

```
<body onLoad="openCity(event,'Paris')">
```

EDIT: to Set an Element to be focused use this:

```
document.getElementById('focusmeplease').focus();
```

Comment: That does load the tab content. However, it doesn't do the CSS highlighting, so the tab control itself appears to have no selection, despite the content from 'Paris' being loaded.

Comment: so for the focus() call, do I do that at the end of `$(document).ready(function (){`?  And, the id 'focusmeplease' would be the ID of my DIV? Sorry, new to js. THanks.

Comment: OK, i added the getElementyById call to a <scrpt> tag at the bottom of my jsp. Focus() doesn't do anything,b ut i can manipulate other attributes, like style.color, and it works. Should my ID be the ID of the DIV or the ID of the list item (tab) ? Neitehr seem to work.

Comment: You need to add a ID to the <a> tag you want to focus in the beginning.
Put the getElementById into `$(document).ready(function (){`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
//style.css

#Paris.is_active{
    display:block;
}

//index.js
$('#Paris').addClass('is_active');
```